# Can iptables rules stop working if i connect to a specific WiFi?

Tags: linux, debian, networking, iptables

I created iptables rules like this:

```
iptables --flush
iptables --delete-chain
iptables -t nat --flush
iptables -t nat --delete-chain
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Does internet work in that case? I guess it shouldn't.

But recently I found a nice cafe in my town and used their WiFi. I was surprised that with their WiFi I have an Internet connection even with the rules above.

How that can be possible?

Thank you for answers.

P.S. I tried to connect to many other hot spots and nowhere that problem appeared, except this cafe's WiFi.

Comment: So what is the output of `iptables -nvL` while you can access the Internet?

Comment: I'll go to this cafe and check it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect something else is running scripts post-connect to modify the firewall rules. You can use `sudo iptables -L -v` to figure out what the currently applied rules are. That being said, I've used several different methods to connect to the internet (first Network Manager, then Wicd, and now systemd-networkd and wpa_supplicant directly) and I've never had any of them modify the firewall rules after connection, so I'm not sure why that is happening. Worst case, you can start a system service which runs `wpa_cli` with an action file that re-applies the firewall rules you desire upon connection (see the wpa_supplicant documentation for more information along with a sample action file).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously other `iptables` calls have been made afterwards, probably by the component which configured the WiFi connection.

Comment: I'm using GNOME's network manager. So, it can did it? Is it possible at all?

Comment: @T.Abrams Software which modifies system interfaces runs with root privileges so it can certainly make changes to the firewall. Maybe that can be prevented by configuration but I am not familiar with NM.

Comment: What do you use to connect to the wifi, if not NM? :)

Comment: @T.Abrams Strange as it may be: I do not have a private notebook. I do use something on the work notebook which may even be NM (or rather the KDE interface for it) but entering a password does not make me familiar with it.